# How do you check if a value is of type "error" in Scheme?

Tags: testing, exception, scheme, r6rs

The manual on [standard libraries for Scheme r6rs](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-8.html#node_chap_7) suggests that if I import the library `(rnrs exceptions (6))` I should be able to call `(error? val)` to check if a given value is an `&error` type. I want to do this for unit testing. I've added the library to my import header and the code compiles, so I know the import is working fine. But DrRacket still recognizes `error?` as undefined. Does anyone know what's going on here?

My code:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base) (rnrs exceptions (6)))
(error? "hello world")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `conditions` library:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs) (rnrs conditions))
(display (error? "hello world"))
```

yields

```
=> #f
```

Comment: Ah, I needed (rnrs conditions) not (rnrs exceptions). Thank you!!

Comment: In DrRacket, position the cursor on the word `error?` and press F1. The first help item says `error?  provided from rnrs/conditions-6`.